When are universal monomorphisms effective?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a nice category, at least one with all equalizers and pushouts (but I'm happy to assume a lot about $\mathcal{C}$, e.g. locally finitely presentable or even that it's the category of models for a multisorted Lawvere theory). Define a morphism $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to be a universal monomorphism if the pushout of $f$ against any other morphism is a monomorphism. When is it the case that every universal monomorphism is an effective monomorphism?
This occurs in $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{CRing}$: monomorphisms are simply the injective homomorphisms, so a universal monomorphism is the same as a pure or universally injective map. It's known that these are exactly the maps which satisfy descent for modules, and by standard stuff about descent/comonadicity $A \to B$ satisfying descent is equivalent to having an equalizer diagram $M \to M \otimes_A B \rightrightarrows M \otimes_A B \otimes_A B$ for every $A$-module $M$. Specializing $M = A$ we see every descent homomorphism is in particular an effective monomorphism.
The proof that pure morphisms satisfy descent is sort of finicky (in my opinion) and doesn't seem to generalize well. Is there some nice categorical structure going on here?
